# Flutter - Dismiss a dialog after pushing to a new page

Tags: flutter

I am currently creating a todo app where if I long pressed a task tile, it will pop up a show dialog. After redirecting to the edit page, you can edit and save the changes. However, once you are done, you will be redirected to the homepage but will be welcomed with the previous dialog How do I dismiss the dialog after you have been directed to the edit page?

Here is the code of the show dialog:

```
Future _showAlert(data) async{
return showDialog<Null>(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: true,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text('Would you like to make changes?', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0)),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text('Edit'),
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new EditTodoPage(todo: data, todoID: selectedTodoId,)));
          },
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          child: new Text('Delete'),
          onPressed: (){
            _delete(selectedTodoId);
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of simply call `pop` to return to home page, you can use `popUntil`.

An example of implementation would be "pop until route '/'", which should be your home.

```
Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
  return route.settings.name == "/";
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Really helped. However, it still appears for a split second after I return to the home page.

Answer (score 7):

`Navigator.push` returns a Future that completes after calling `Navigator.pop` on your edit page.

You can dismiss your dialog after that, like this:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(/* ... */)
    .then((result) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
},
```

Comment: thanks! I also have the same problem. It worked really well. ;)